# C++ Builder nullptr keyword "Undefined"

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr, c++builder-10.1-berlin

In C++ Builder (Berlin) the editor's syntax highlighter shows `nullptr` as a reserved word. But when compiling I get the error:

```
Undefined symbol 'nullptr'
```

`nullptr` was added to the C++11 standard and as far I know, C++ Builder Berlin supports C++11. I have been browsing the C++ Compiler options but can't find anything related to selecting what C++ standard to use.

Is `nullptr` not supported in C++ Builder Berlin and the highlighter is just buggy? Or can I turn on C++11 support somewhere?

Comment: Have you already tried this: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=872315&tstart=0 ?

Comment: Ahh! I always have a hard time to find my way on Embarcadero's site. I usually google or check SO instead ;) Can you write down the steps so I can mark it as the solution and you get your reps?

Comment: Well, I don't have that IDE installed, so I can't check any of those steps. My "answer" couldn't be nothing more than some quotes from that link. On the other hand, *you* could post an answer to your own question, if you managed to solve the issue.

Comment: I thought that was understood that your link solved it. But if you can't verify it yourself and don't feel comfortable with just writing an answer without testing it's fine. I can write my own version in 2 days (unless you have written one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as far I know, C++ Builder Berlin supports C++11.

To be more accurate, only its [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang) support C++11. The ["classic" Windows 32-bit compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32) does not.

When compiling for Windows 32-bit, you can specify in the Project Options whether to use the Classic or Clang compiler. Per Embarcadero's documentation:

[How to use the Clang-based compiler for Windows 32-bit projects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers#How_to_use_the_Clang-based_compiler_for_Windows_32-bit_projects):

> BCC32C and BCC32X do not replace [BCC32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32), RAD Studio gives you the option to choose the compiler for each of your projects. **BCC32 is the default C++ compiler for 32-bit Windows**.
>
> To enable BCC32C or BCC32X for a specific project, select `Project > Options > C++ Compiler` and **disable the `Use 'classic' Borland compiler` option** under `Classic Compiler`.
>
> The IDE will now use the Clang-enhanced Win32 compiler.